# How to compare multiple variables to multiple variables in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, compare

I have four variables:

`valueOne`, `valueTwo`, `valueThree` and `valueFour`. I want to compare them to other four variables (lets say `firstValue`, `secondValue`, `thirdValue` and `fourthValue`), and if they do not match, I want to update them:

```
if valueOne != firstValue {
    valueOne = firstValue
}
```

How can I do this effectively for every single variable? Meaning:
`if valueOne != firstValue`, `valueTwo != secondValue`, `valueThree != thirdValue` and so on.

Comment: Assignment is normally cheaper than a compare (no branching when assigning), so just do the assignment. Unless it's a special case, like a register which triggers something when you write to it, but I don't expect you'd do that in Swift.

Comment: You don't need to compare.  Whatever the values, the final four values you want are the second set so just assign them to the first 4 properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as simple as:

```
(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree, valueFour) = (firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, fourthValue)
```

<sub>Use `==` if you only want to compare</sub>

Comment: Wrapping groups of `Comparable` values in a tuple and using `if (val1, val2) == (otherVal1, otherVal2)` is a good solution. (Voted).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```swift
func compareable<T: Comparable>(baseValues: [T], valueToCompare values: [T]) -> [T] {
    assert(baseValues.count == values.count, "Total elements must equal")
    var _baseValues: [T] = baseValues
    for i in 0..<_baseValues.count {
        if _baseValues[i] != values[i] {
            _baseValues[i] = values[i]
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    return _baseValues
}

//Type check
compareable(baseValues: [1,2,3,4], valueToCompare: [false,false,true,true]) //Error
compareable(baseValues: [1,2,3,4], valueToCompare: ["1","2","3","4"]) //Error

//Use
compareable(baseValues: [1,2,3,4], valueToCompare: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]) //Return [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
compareable(baseValues: [1,2,3,4], valueToCompare: [5,6,7,8]) //Return [Int] = [5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Looks good, but unfortunately my values are not the same type -> this would return the "Type "Any" cannot conform to "Comparable"" error.

Comment: Casting to Any type is risky and makes no sense. It would help if you thought about it, the variables need some constraints to compare each other.